# Updating a table With a Dataframe

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm using data in a dataframe to try and update a table in an sqlite database that looks like

```
Part | Price
------------
  a  |  5
  b  |  9
```

I am getting a syntax error for this

```
for(row in 1:nrow(newdata)){dbGetQuery(conn=db,"UPDATE Parts SET Price = ",newdata$Price[row], " WHERE Part = '", newdata$Part[row],"';")}
```

The exact error I'm getting:

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near " ": syntax error

Why is this please?

Comment: The query has to be a single string: you'll have to `paste` it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string needs to be built into a single string

```
for(row in seq_len(nrow(newdata))) {
  dbGetQuery(conn=db, sprintf("UPDATE Parts SET Price = %i WHERE Part = '%s';", newdata$Price[row], newdata$Part[row]))
```

}

It's also possible to accomplish this with `paste` or `paste0`, but `sprintf` can be easier to read.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I just had to change %i because it had an invalid format error